# Very spookie integral involving powers of 3/4 and hypergeomteric functions.

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

What is the anti derivative of $(2x^2+9)^{3/4}$? I tried standard methods and even more complex methods but couldn't get it to work. I know that wolfram and maple give something in terms of hypergeometric functions but how do they arrive at this?

Comment: The word you're looking for is trigonometric functions.  Whenever you have an integrand of the form $(ax^2+b)^c$ you can try to use a trig substitution to transform the integrand into a more workable form.

Comment: If it was trivial would be done by now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use $x=\frac{3}{\sqrt{2}}\tan t$.
\begin{align}
\int \frac{dx}{(2x^2+9)^{3/4}} 
&= 
 \frac{1}{\sqrt{6}}\int \frac{\sec^2t\ dt}{(\tan^2t+1)^{3/4}}
\\
& =  \frac{1}{\sqrt{6}}\int \frac{dt}{\sqrt{\cos t}}
\\
& =  \frac{1}{\sqrt{6}}\int \frac{dt}{\sqrt{1-2\sin^2 (\frac{t}{2})}}
\\
& =  \frac{2}{\sqrt{6}}\int \frac{du}{\sqrt{1-2\sin^2 u}}
\\
& =  \frac{2}{\sqrt{6}}F(x,2)
\end{align}

where the answer is an [elliptic integral](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EllipticIntegraloftheFirstKind.html) of the first kind.